# Dojo FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo

I'm using Dojo v1.8 Filtering Select Component. I have some text inside the drop down. When i type a text inside the filtering select, i found some characters were cutting of the length and displaying outside the filtering Select box.

**Note: i must turn on the force width attribute and cannot be removed.**

Kindly find the jsfiddle url, where i have kept my sample code.Type "All" , and the issue is reproduced.

URl : jsfiddle.net/sumanth418/KUH3P/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting bug you found. It seems that the menu item CSS code is actually using the following CSS property:

```css
.dijitMenuItem {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This means that if the content doesn't fix in the box, it will not create a new line, but it will in fact just go through (and that's the effect you're seeing). That alone is no problem if the `overflow` property is defined somewhere. If I look at the CSS of the `dijitComboBoxMenu`, I notice that the following is present:

```css
.dijitComboBoxMenu {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Both CSS properties combined, makes it so that the content will overflow and that the overflowing content will be visible as well.

---

This looks like a bug, and indeed it is. If I run your code using Dojo 1.9.1, the problem is solved and the overflowing content is invisible.

To manually fix your problem (if upgrading to Dojo 1.9.1 is no possibility), you could do several things:

1. Change the `white-space` property to `inherit`. This will cause the overflowing content to be displayed on the next line.
2. Change the `overflow` prperty of `dijitMenuItem` to `hidden`. This will hide the overflowing content (like the fix in Dojo 1.9.1)
3. Change the `overflow` property of `dijitComboBoxMenu` to `scroll`. This will add a horizontal and vertical scrollbar to the combobox menu. However, because the `overflow` is overriden by inline CSS, you need to append the `!important` modifier
4. If you dislike the vertical scrollbar from solution 3, you can use:

```css
.dijitComboBoxMenu {
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

However, the `overflow-x` property is a CSS3 property which might not work on older browsers.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, this is the solutions which i'm looking for. Solution 4 is perfect for us. Once again Thanks.

Comment: One quick question, This is working fine absolutely. Consider, i have data which has length less than the width of the filtering box, even then i see the horizontal scrollbar. Is there any way to overcome it, like doing a validation based on the Height. Since we are using "maxHeight" attribute, the horizontal scrollbar should appear only if it didnot reach the maxHeight. Because, once it reaches the maxHeight, ByDefault the scrollbars appear.

Note: There exists a disabled Horizontal scroll bar.

URL : http://jsfiddle.net/sumanth418/KUH3P/

Type "A" to reproduce the issue

Comment: I have no idea what you exactly mean.